# CONCAT columns without sub-query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, concatenation

I was looking to see if there was a better approach to this query

The date field is formatted - 06-03-2018

I need a column that looks like e.g. Mar-18
e.g

```
SELECT
CONCAT(P.[Month] + '-', p.[Year]) AS [Month-Year]
FROM
(
SELECT 
left(datename(MONTH,[Date]),3) AS [Month]
,right(YEAR([Date]),2) AS [Year]
FROM
Table1
)P
```

This gives me the result i want but i was wondering if there was anyway to get the same result without a sub-query. Thanks

Comment: YOu don't need the subquery or `datename` etc. You can use FORMAT to format a value, eg a datetime or `CONVERT` with a format code in old versions of SQL Server. Even if you wanted to use `DATENAME` you can put everything in a single SELECT

Comment: `select format(getdate(),'MMM-yy')` is enough

Comment: BTW the best place to format dates is the *client*, not the query. It's a *lot* easier and faster to specify the desired format, culture (ie language) etc on a control's or report's Format property

Comment: The fastest option to format in the database is probably to not do it at all. Create a Calendar table with extra columns for month names, years, or any formats you want to use in your reports. This would allow reporting tools to filter by the formatted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just format the date as

```
select format(convert(date, '06-03-2018', 103), 'MMM-yy')
```

Comment: I feel like I always have to mention that `FORMAT` is quite a slow function. It's "fine" with a single value, or 2, but for large datasets I recommend avoiding it.

Comment: @Larnu calling datename, year and then concatenating won't be faster. The proper way to format is the client anyway, not the server

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wanna bet? My answer for 2393770 rows: `CPU time = 2250 ms,  elapsed time = 13749 ms.`. Using `FORMAT`: `CPU time = 84453 ms,  elapsed time = 94860 ms.`. I'd say that is **significantly** faster. I suggest doing some testing before you make a statement like that. :) From experience, `FORMAT` is an awful function, because of how slow it is. It was a nice idea, but it need a lot of improvement.

Comment: Not saying, however, that the correct way to format isn't in the Client (it is, and I agree on that); just that `DATENAME`, `Year` and concatenating is far faster than using `FORMAT`

Comment: @Larnu I don't bet. I set the `NumberFormat` in the report field. Or I use a Calendar table - much faster than any formatting option

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have already proved that `FORMAT` is slower in my comment...  if you don't beleive that, I suggest you try yourself. As i said in my above comments, your statement *"calling datename, year and then concatenating won't be faster."* is simply wrong and not true. *"The proper way to format is the client anyway, not the server "* is true, however, the former part of it is wrong. As I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

The query you've provided isn't valid, you need a comma (`,`) between column declarations (which you're missing.

Anyway, the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[Date]),3) + '-' + RIGHT(YEAR([Date]),2) AS [Month-Year]
FROM Table1;
```

I haven't used `CONCAT` here, as there is no need (as either both values will be *`NULL`* or have a value).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do the concatenation directly

```
SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(datename(MONTH, [Date]), 3) AS VARCHAR(20))
    +'-'+
    CAST(RIGHT(YEAR([Date]), 2) AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM Table1;
```